# "Super" utilisé comme un adverbe

Tags: adverbes

Le mot *super* peut-il être utilisé comme un adverbe, comme dans *j'ai trouvé ça super bien* ? Ça ne me semble pas correct (pour moi, il ne s'agit que d'un préfixe et d'un adjectif), mais c'est une tournure que j'entends beaucpup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est correct mais grave familier. *Super* peut être un adjectif, un adverbe ou une interjection (voir [le site du CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/super))).
Adjectif:

> C'était super et chérot (Queneau)

Adverbe, avec le sens de *remarquablement, extraordinairement*, titre d'un roman de Gary Shteyngart :

> Super triste histoire d'amour.

Interjection :

> Super ! Les parents sont pas là, je vais pouvoir regarder le TV.